# Is it possible to combine dask.DataFrame.categorize with another dask computation using dask.compute?

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to avoid repeating dask compute using `dask.compute(list_of_dask_computations)`. In the code I have, I have to create some categorical columns in a dask dataframe and call `dask.DataFrame.categorize` to make categories as known. But I would like to do that call at the same time as other computations on other columns as provided by `dask.compute(list_of_dask_computations)`. But I don't see how.

An example is described below:

```
import dask
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df['letter'] = df['name'].str[0].astype('category')
mean_x = df['x'].mean()
mean_y = df['y'].mean()

# How to combine these two computations below
mean_x_val, mean_y_val = dask.compute(mean_x, mean_y)
df=df.categorize(columns=['letter']) # or df['letter']=df['letter'].cat.as_known()
```

Thanks for any help available.

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `df.categorize` implictly calls `compute` internally.  My guess is that there isn't an easy way to combine that with other compute calls at the same time.  Ideally that would be changed.

Comment: Thank @MRocklin for the answer. I understand the difficulty, especially if we consider some SOLID concept, it is very difficult to handle those needs in the same call.
But I have a subsidiary question: when I call df.categorize on some columns only, or if at the end of my graph I just select a dataframe with a subset of columns, does Dask compute all the columns that were ever added to graph at some points, even if they were never used to generate the final columns I need ?